# Fetch request post method in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I cannot make it work the fetch request with the post method, with get other  api calls works great.This is my code:

```
return fetch(URL_LOCAL + `/addLike`, {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify({a: 1})
})
    .then(response => Promise.all([response, response.json()]))
    .catch(err => {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    })
```

I made a console.log before the fetch about the URL_LOCAL and its fine it returns http://localhost:5000.

It gives me this error:

```
Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (blob:http://localhost:8081/459df9ca-c7b8-48bc-9c45-03d2f1e94f1d:15825)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (blob:http://localhost:8081/459df9ca-c7b8-48bc-9c45-03d2f1e94f1d:17902)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (blob:http://localhost:8081/459df9ca-c7b8-48bc-9c45-03d2f1e94f1d:17657)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (blob:http://localhost:8081/459df9ca-c7b8-48bc-9c45-03d2f1e94f1d:17484)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/459df9ca-c7b8-48bc-9c45-03d2f1e94f1d:17594
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (blob:http://localhost:8081/459df9ca-c7b8-48bc-9c45-03d2f1e94f1d:3480)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (blob:http://localhost:8081/459df9ca-c7b8-48bc-9c45-03d2f1e94f1d:2386)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/459df9ca-c7b8-48bc-9c45-03d2f1e94f1d:2156
    at MessageQueue.__guardSafe (blob:http://localhost:8081/459df9ca-c7b8-48bc-9c45-03d2f1e94f1d:2348)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (blob:http://localhost:8081/459df9ca-c7b8-48bc-9c45-03d2f1e94f1d:2155)
```

I'am on an android simulator using chrome dev tools to see the logs, and i'am using node and mongodb as backend , but i put a log in the beginning of the call but is not fired

EDIT:
I make it work but with the api in production is the same code that i used with localhost:5000, I dont know what can be wrong with the localhost

Comment: Is there a `.code` on the error object? Other details? That might tell you more.

Comment: @Jacob No, i only get logged the error that i describe above. Is the error returned from the .catch

Comment: I am not sure why you are returning promise from ``.then`` of fetch. ``response`` and ``response.json`` are not promise objects.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the error has more details than what you posted. Log those out and we'll understand exactly what _kind_ of network request failure this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try replacing your code with following:

```
return fetch(URL_LOCAL + `/addLike`, {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify({a: 1})
})
    .then(response => Promise.resolve(response.json()))
    .catch(err => {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue.

I was developing locally and my API was running inside a docker container on my machine. My React Native App was managed by **Expo**, hence I was using a phone connected on the *same network* as my machine to test the app.

**What I was doing wrong** was trying to send fetch requests to `127.0.0.1:PORT/api/endpoints` or `localhost:PORT/api/endpoints`.
The problem was that requests were coming from my phone and were supposed to be sent to the API which is not at 127.0.0.1/localhost anymore if we are on the phone but at the address of my machine on the same network as my phone. Stupid right?

**What I did to fix this** was to get the current IP of my machine on my local network, the same network as where my phone was connected, used it as IP address of the API.

So instead of doing

```
fetch('localhost:8000/api/v2/events/upcoming')
```

I discovered that Expo was fetching the react app from 192.168.0.110:19000. Meaning that 192.168.0.110 was my machine's IP on the network. So, the right fetch request was

```
fetch('192.168.0.110:8000/api/v2/events/upcoming')
```