# How to convert XMLHttpRequest to Fetch?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core-mvc, fetch

I have again trouble to understand how to use `Fetch`. I need to send an object to ASP.NET controller.

I have `XMLHttpRequest` (that works):

```
handleProductSubmit(product) {
        const products = this.state.data;
        product.productID = products.length + 1;
        const newProducts = products.concat([product]);
        this.setState({ data: newProducts });

        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('Name', product.Name);
        data.append('Description', product.Description);

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', this.props.submitUrl, true);
        xhr.onload = () => this.loadProductsFromServer();
        xhr.send(data);
    }
```

And with `Fetch` I figured out only this:

```
handleProductSubmit(product) {
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('Name', product.Name);
        data.append('Description', product.Description);
        console.log(data);
        fetch("/comments/new?product=" + encodeURIComponent(data))
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }
```

And it returns to the controller `null`.

Comment: Do you want to do a POST or GET request? In the fetch example you are doing a GET request with the form data as query parameters in the url but I see you original intention was a POST request with form data in the request body

Comment: On server I have `get`, I just forgot to change it on `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: I think it is somewhat related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51663669/fetch-request-post-method-in-react-native.

Comment: @AndrésRoberto yeah, I know, but I just had no idea what to stick there. Nothing like `body: data` did not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
const queryParams = `Name=${encodeURIComponent(product.name)}&Description=${encodeURIComponent(product.Description)}`;
fetch(`/comments/new?${queryParams}`)
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly I am still getting null.

Comment: May I see a log of what is sent? perhaps from the Network tab in the dev tools?

Comment: GET request: `http://localhost:61798/comments/new?Name%3Dundefined%26Description%3Dtest`

Comment: 1. Don't encode the query string. Just the values. I've updated the answer to reflect so.
2. Seems like `product.name` is undefined. Make sure you are passing something there

Comment: 1. it worked! 2. it was only because used lower case. 3. is it JS syyntax? 4. thanks!

Comment: 1. Yay! 3. If you mean the interpolation, it's called template literals and you can read more about it in MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals. 4. Happy to help!