# Fetch with Post method in React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to do a fetch with the post method in my react-native, but I receive always an error:

```
TypeError: Network request failed
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (whatwg-fetch.js:504)
at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:580)
at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:394)
at XMLHttpRequest.js:507
at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:181)
at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:366)
at MessageQueue.js:106
at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:314)
at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (MessageQueue.js:105)
```

**User creationg page**

```
static createUser(Identity, FirstName, LastName, FiscalCode , Email) {

    let formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('Identity', JSON.stringify(Identity));
    formdata.append('FirstName', (FirstName));
    formdata.append('LastName', LastName);
    formdata.append('FiscalCode', FiscalCode);
    formdata.append('Email', Email);



    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {

        fetch('https://linktomyapi.com' , {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                },
           body: formdata
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
            if(responseData.Error){
                Alert.alert("Errore");
            }
            global.utente = responseData;
            resolve(responseData)
        })
        .catch((err) => {reject(err)})
    })
}
```

About Identity, I take in this way:

```
let Identity = 
           {
               AppName: 
               {
                    Username: this.state.FiscalCode,
                    Password: this.state.Password
               }
           }
```

I follow many guides about this argoument, but I don't understand why I receive these errors.

Comment: have you referred <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51663669/fetch-request-post-method-in-react-native> or <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44996357/react-fetch-post-request>

Comment: @kish I tried what they suggest but nothing change :/

Comment: Does the server have the appropriate API?

Comment: @hongdevelop yes I have tested with CocoaRest and It works. It's a problem only about the signup. With the login it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following?

```
let params = {
Identity: JSON.stringify(Identity),
FirstName: FirstName,
LastName: LastName,
FiscalCode: FiscalCode,
Email: Email
}
return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {

        fetch('https://linktomyapi.com' , {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
           ...(params && { body: JSON.stringify(params) })
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
            if(responseData.Error){
                Alert.alert("Errore");
            }
            global.utente = responseData;
            resolve(responseData)
        })
        .catch((err) => {reject(err)})
    })
```

Are sure your content type is formdata?

Comment: I tried now and I receive this: 
Error: unsupported BodyInit type
    at Request.Body._initBody (whatwg-fetch.js:279)
    at new Request (whatwg-fetch.js:398)
    at whatwg-fetch.js:486
    at tryCallTwo (core.js:45)
    at doResolve (core.js:200)
    at new Promise (core.js:66)
    at self.fetch (whatwg-fetch.js:485)
    at User.js:38
    at tryCallTwo (core.js:45)
    at doResolve (core.js:200)

Comment: thank for your support, but I receive the same error of my beggining post now :/

Comment: @Jack23 do you have to use `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`?, can you send json data to the server?

Comment: @JuniusL. Yes in the API the headers is 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'.
Yes I can send json data to the server

Comment: and you don't need that `new Promise`, you can just return `return fetch(...);` without  `then` and `catch`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {

        fetch('https://linktomyapi.com' , {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                },
           body: formdata
        })
```

In the fetch I pass the link as a string.

So the **correct form** is:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {

        fetch(https://linktomyapi.com , {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                },
           body: formdata
        })
```